# Android MySql connection error

Tags: android

I have to load data from a remote mysql database for my app. The table contains event id, event name and event details. I have to get the last data from the table and show it in 3 text views. I tried a tutorial from androidhive. But it doesn't seem to work. please help.

class to retrieve the data

```
class GetEventDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading data from servers. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        //String pid="1";
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray eventObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_EVENT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject event = eventObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            TextView txtEventname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                            TextView txtEventdet=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                            // Edit Text
                            txtEventname.setText(event.getString(TAG_EVENTITLE));
                            txtEventdet.setText(event.getString(TAG_EVENTDET));
                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }


}
```

the Jason parsor class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

My error is

```
04-28 15:43:29.918: D/dalvikvm(8036): Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-28 15:43:30.278: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 12% free 9560K/10759K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
04-28 15:43:30.288: I/dalvikvm-heap(8036): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.705MB for 437672-byte allocation
04-28 15:43:30.358: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 9986K/11207K, paused 13ms+7ms, total 70ms
04-28 15:43:30.358: D/dalvikvm(8036): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 55ms
04-28 15:43:30.449: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 11% free 10211K/11463K, paused 56ms, total 57ms
04-28 15:43:30.649: D/libEGL(8036): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-28 15:43:30.759: D/libEGL(8036): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-28 15:43:30.789: D/libEGL(8036): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-28 15:43:30.879: D/OpenGLRenderer(8036): Enabling debug mode 0
04-28 15:43:32.130: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_CONCURRENT freed 11K, 9% free 10906K/11975K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 56ms
04-28 15:43:32.130: D/dalvikvm(8036): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
04-28 15:43:32.200: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 11335K/12487K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
04-28 15:43:32.290: D/dalvikvm(8036): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 8% free 11992K/12999K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 71ms
04-28 15:43:32.681: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8036): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-28 15:43:32.681: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8036): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-28 15:43:34.422: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8036): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-28 15:43:34.422: E/SpannableStringBuilder(8036): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-28 15:43:35.994: D/ProgressBar(8036): setProgress = 0
04-28 15:43:35.994: D/ProgressBar(8036): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
04-28 15:43:35.994: D/ProgressBar(8036): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
04-28 15:43:36.124: W/ResourceType(8036): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c8 (t=7 e=712) in package 0 (error -75)
04-28 15:43:36.474: D/AndroidRuntime(8036): Shutting down VM
04-28 15:43:36.474: W/dalvikvm(8036): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a162a0)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at com.mahavega.qcdemo.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at com.mahavega.qcdemo.MainActivity$GetEventDetails$1.run(MainActivity.java:198)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04-28 15:43:36.534: E/AndroidRuntime(8036):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please do not create UI Thread inside the doInbackground() method

Comment: yet another NOMTException question ...

Comment: [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException)

Answer (score 2):

You create an AsyncTask, then you put everything in the body there in a runOnUiThread.  That completely cancels out the AsyncTask, its the equivalent of not having one.  Remove that part, you want it directly in the doInBackground function.